# Is it possible to check if a string is in a class nested in a class in Python?

Tags: python, class

I have created a class in Python with classes nested in it:

```py
class example:
     class example_in_class:
          exampleKey = "exampleItem"
          exampleKey2 = "exampleItem2"
          thisOne = "thisone"
          exampleKey3 = "exampleItem3"
          exampleKey4 = "exampleItem4"

     class example_in_class2:
          exampleKey = "exampleItem2"
          exampleKey2 = "exampleItem22"
          thisOne = "NOTthisone"
          exampleKey3 = "exampleItem32"
          exampleKey4 = "exampleItem42"
```

Now I want to see if I can find the item `"thisone"` without specifying the class.

Is it like `example.include("thisone")` or something?

I have searched this all over google but it isn't a human so I don't know how to word it so it understands...

Comment: No; don't use a class as a container. Use a list or a dict.

Comment: is there a way to nest dictionaries in a dictionary?

Comment: Sure: `{'things': {'more_things': {'even_more_things': []}}}`

Comment: ya just stick the dictionary into the meta-dictionary like you would any other object. In python, *everything* is fundamentally an object

Comment: yes just like this .. d = {'1':{'1':'a','2':'b'},'2':{'1':'a','2':'b'}}...the value of your dictionary entry can be a dictionary

Comment: thanks! And is there a way to return the key using only the value with dict nested in dict?

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy Maybe try writing some code to search through the nested dictionary, and come back when you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would ever want to do such a thing, but here it is:

```
def find_thisone(cls):
    for attr in cls.__dict__.values():
        if type(attr) != type:
            continue
        if 'thisone' in attr.__dict__.values():
            return attr
```

This function will find you the nested class that has a string attribute with value `thisone`:

```
>>> find_thisone(example)
__main__.example.example_in_class
```

But for real, you're better off heeding the suggestions in the comments.

**Edit:** An explanation: `.__dict__` allows you to iterate through an object's attributes just like a dictionary object. The dictionary has `keys()` and `values()`. The names of the nested classes will be in the `keys()`, and the actual classes will be in the `values()`. By checking whether the `type()` of each value is itself a `type`, i.e. a class, we can get at the nested classes without worrying about any other attributes of the outer class. Then we likewise access the attributes of the nested class using `.__dict__.values()` and check if the string `'thisone'` is among them. If so, we've found the right nested class.